# git windows clone of svn repository tries to create a folder name with colon in it

Tags: git, msysgit

I created a git clone of http://code.google.com/p/jpcsp/ . I later tried to update to the latest revision by fetching , merging , reseting and a bunch of other things which I can't remember all or the order in which they are . At the moment the git local repository is with the HEAD at the initial clone latest revision , I can't rebase (lists things that need updating and then says 'update index --refresh: command returned error:1') and can't checkout things after svn revision 1005 I think .

The primary issue seems to be that at revision 1006 a file with the name 'G:[...]' was commited to svn and then deleted the following revision . Now all the significant commands fail , for example 'fatal: cannot create directory at G:[...]' is the error message from 'git checkout -f HEAD' . HEAD is now at the initial clone which is 1994 in svn . So it is trying to create a folder with G: in the name which is unacceptable for windows . Also the command 'git ls-tree HEAD' has in it's output the following tree line : '[...] tree [sha1] "G:\[...]"' which seems to be the local folder path on the computer of the fellow that commited the 1006 revision to the svn repository - mabe this causes the checkout of the 1994 revision's git equivalent to fail . Another thing that may be causing problems is the fact that my computer sees imaginary removable drives including G: that aren't there in the first place - this was since I bought it more then a year ago and which may or may not be confusing git .

I created a message in the msysgit mailing list as well at http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/dfdeae9a85f3f534 with more details about some commands I made on the command line and their output , but I was also even more confused since I thought the issue was different .

One thing I tried and didn't work was to do a git rebase -i and then something like squash , but git was still complaining about not being able to create a folder with G:[...]

Today I have recloned the svn repository in another folder and it gave errors as well . Then the first checkout of the latest svn revision returned the same cannot create folder error .

If anybody knows how to fix a problem like this one I could use some help . And I won't accept suggestion that start with use svn because the remote repository is svn .

--<>EDIT<>-- :
 The solution with 'git svn fetch -r0:' and 'git svn fetch -r:HEAD' seems to work . I now have a checkout of the latest svn commit and a log of the entire history of the project except 2 commits . I received the message that the repository is in detached HEAD though so I'll have to investigate what that means .
I have some questions about the new situation . I suppose I should fetch with revision numbers from now on from svn for as long as I keep this local git repository ? And would this impact my ability to dcommit at a later point ?

Comment: Cygwin does support colons and other such reserved characters in filenames on Windows (by mapping to the Unicode private use area), so you might want to try Cygwin git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are better ways, but you can try:

```
$ git svn fetch -r<last revision fetched>:<faulty revision -1>
$ git svn fetch -r<fault revision +2>:<latest revision>
```

Comment: That is not helping me checkout from the local repository , where it complains about not being able to create the folder with G: in it .

Comment: If you clone or fetch without that revision and the reverting revision, the checkout wont try to create it.

Comment: So it seems to work since I can checkout the latest commit version and I have a log for the entire history of the project , even though it says it is in detached HEAD at the moment which I have to investigate .